# Pointing to the front of a linked list after deleting all nodes with value N?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, nodes

The following is a function that is supposed to do three things:

1.Delete all nodes of value N (`char key`) in a linked list (the values are always single char character.)

2.Return the head of the linked list.

3.All of this must be done recursively.

```
node* deleteN(node* head, char key)
    {
        node* prev;
        node* cur;

        if (head == NULL)
            return NULL;

        prev = head;
        cur = head->next;

        if (head->data == key && head->next != NULL)
        {
            node* temp = head;

            head = temp->next;

            free(temp);
        }

        if (cur->data == key && cur->next == NULL)
        {
            free(cur);

            prev->next = NULL;
        }

        head->next = deleteN(head->next, key);

        return head;

    }
```

My problem is I can delete the nodes just fine and as you can see I have a special case if the node is the final node in the list. However, when I return head, head is pointing to nothing and causes crashes when I try to do other things with the linked list.

**My question is: How can I get head to point to the front of the linked list (where it started) at the end of the function after deleting all nodes of value N, and return this pointer?**

Comment: keep it saved/update at each insertion/deletion operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rebuild the list from the recursion:

```
node* deleteN(node* head, char key)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    return NULL;

  node* tail = deleteN(head->next, key);
  if (head->data == key) {
    free(head);
    return tail;
  } else {
    head->next = tail;
    return head;
  }
}
```